# Pyint tip 'Unable to import <module>'

Tags: pylint

```
testproject/src/pkga/pkgb/pkgc/module.py

testproject/test/pkga/pkgb/pkgc/module_test.py
```

src and test is the source folder,

src/pkga and test/pkga is the root package

in file module_test.py

```
from pkga.pkgb.pkgc import module
```

pylint module_test.py will tip `Unable to import pkga.pkgb.pkgc` even add 'testproject/src/' to the `PYTHONPATH`

it's seems pylint will only find 'pkga/pkgb/pkgc/module.py' in dir 'testproject/test/'

however, it will be ok if change 'testproject/src/pkga/pkgb/pkgc/module.py' to 'testproject/src/pkganew/pkgb/pkgc/module.py'

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you run `python module_test.py`? Which directories have `__init__.py` file ?

I suppose that there is either a PYTHONPATH problem or a package conflict, i.e. pylint/python picks the first `pkga` package directory, which is probably the one where `module_test` is, hence does'nt find `module` in it.

Comment: Yes, python module_test.py work. All the packages (pkga, pkgb, pkgc) have a __init__.py file. Python run is ok , but pylint not.

Comment: Then there is probably package magic in some __init__.py file that pylint doesn't grasp. You may want to submit a gist on pylint's tracker (https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint).